# Google Gson - adding arrays to a List

Tags: java, gson

I want to make sure if it's good. Maybe there is another better solution.

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        String[] arr = { String.valueOf(i) };
        list.add(arr);
    }

    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Expected output:

> ```
> [
> [
> "0"
> ],
> [
> "1"
> ],
> [
> "2"
> ]
> ]
> ```

Comment: Please give a brief explanation of the purpose of the code in the question. Even quoting verbatim is ok (if the licence allows it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to use Java 8 you can use streams:

```
List<String[]> list = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .mapToObj(i -> new String[] { String.valueOf(i) })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Let's break it down:

- `IntStream.range(0, 3)` gives you the values 0, 1 and 2
- `.mapToObj(i -> new String[] { String.valueOf(i) })` converts them to a string and puts them into a `String[]`
- `.collect(Collectors.toList())` collects the stream into a `List<String[]>`

Comment: +1, but unfortunately I can't use java 8